# Git(Hub): Syncing repo without cloning all files

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-remote

Given I have a fork of a huge repo, which I want to keep updated with the branch upstream.

Sadly, my internet connection is currently very bad and I can't fetch everything remote, merge and push it again. Is it possible to create a "ghost" clone, that is, a clone without the actual files, just a list of commits?

Then I could just fetch upstream, merge into master and push again to keep it synced, without actually all the time downloading all new diffs.

An alternative would ofcourse be an option in the GitHub Webinterface to merge a Pull Request without creating an additional commit, when it's only fast-forwarding.

Or is there an other way of doing that?